# How to use lock_guard with shared_ptr<mutex>?

Tags: c++, mutex, shared-ptr

How do I lock on **shared_ptr< mutex>** with lock_guard? I tried to do it the way below, but somehow it causes SEGFAULT. What is the right way to do it?

```
struct Component {
   shared_ptr<mutex> mtx;
   Component(){
      mtx = make_shared<mutex>();
   }
   void fun(){
      lock_guard<mutex> l(*mtx.get()); <= is that safe?
      //some stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  The code you have is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't call `*mtx.get()` correct, what's wrong with `*mtx`?